# Unable to render javascript HERE Maps API v3.1 within app created with SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to render the map in one of my SAP UI5 app. I followed the documentation, after which i was able to initialize the `H.service.Platform`. But when I initialize `H.Map()` the map does not render. Upon debugging found out a call
https://js.hereapi.com/v3/3.1.9.0/styles/omv/normal.day.yaml?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=myApiKey is made which fails as the address is never found.

So I tried to build a normal HTML project which worked fine. Upon debugging found out the call for the same came out to be
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1//styles/omv/normal.day.yaml

As you can see there is a difference in the URL.

I tried setting the baseUrl parameter in the `H.service.Platform()` to `baseUrl: new H.service.Url('https', 'api.here.com')`.
This works for the above-mentioned request, but the rest of the requests fail now.
For eg.https://1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=myApiKey&output=json
fails

(it worked before setting baseUrl parameter)

The code used is

```
if (H) {
            var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                apikey: myApiKey
                    /*,
                                        baseUrl: new H.service.Url('https', 'api.here.com')*/
            });

            // Get an object containing the default map layers:
            var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

            // Instantiate the map using the vecor map with the
            // default style as the base layer:
            var map = new H.Map(this.byId("mapBox").getDomRef(),
                defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
                    center: {
                        lat: 50,
                        lng: 5
                    },
                    zoom: 4,
                    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
                });

            var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

            // Create the default UI components
            var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Utkanos added the code.

Comment: @AkshayTamhane , Your question is lil confusing, Could please clarify what exactly you want to achieve. (your use-case)

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Use case is simple. Render map in SAP UI5(a framework) application. Like I have mentioned, I used https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js as my starting point but it's failing in UI5. In my question, I have also explained what could be root cause i.e. the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is difficult to reproduce as it's happening within specific framework, but try to re-set the style for vector normal map layer after creating defaultLayers:

```js
defaultLayers.vector.normal.map.getProvider().setStyle(
  new H.map.Style('https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/styles/omv/normal.day.yaml')
);
```

Comment: after following your step I was able to get the map rendered. However, executing `platform.getBaseUrl()` an object `{s: "https"
c: "hereapi.com" }` is returned. You will be see the difference in the URLs which is boggling me. Don't want to go with hard code approach. If your suggested approach is the only approach, then it is what it is. Thank you!

Comment: But that's correct. 
Platform's baseURL is responsible for communicating with HERE services. By default `platform.getBaseUrl().toString()` returns `https://hereapi.com/?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.10.0&apikey=...`.
It has nothing to do with loading yaml config file.